# Cannot remove long project names from Recent Projects list

Tags: intellij-idea

New IDEA 11. It's been implemented to remove recent projects from the Recent Projects list. When I hover the name of the project, a small X appears which removes the entry.

However, when I have a project with a long name (or long path) and the project name cannot be fully visible in the recent projects list (see image, project no.2)

[image]

then I get **no X** on hover and I cannot remove the project.

Can anyone help?

PS. I know that I can either delete the whole list or edit XML conf file and delete manually entries, but I would prefer if there is a trick to remove long-name projects via IDEA UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this problem, please [vote for the bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82330) I've submitted in YouTrack.